# Lex error Unrecognized rule

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

Hi I am new to lex and have been trying to write a program to extract identifiers. But it shows error on line 9

```
{id} {printf("%s:IDENTIFIER",yytext);}
```

"unrecognized rule"
Here is the code:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
digit [0-9]
letter [a-zA-Z]
id {letter}{letter|digit}*
%%
{id} {printf("%s:IDENTIFIER",yytext);}
%%
int main()
{
yylex();
return 0;
}
```

I have seen other questions also but could find the error in this code.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `id` incorrectly.  Flex is looking for a character class named `letter|digit` but can't find it.  You need to factor your regular expression out of the `{` `}` pair.

```
id {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
```